# tensorflow function in graph mode (tf.function) is slow when return object

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a function wrapped by `@tf.function`, the function was quick when it doen't return any object. But it becomes significant slower when it return an object.

Any way to boost the performance even when it has to return an object?

Below is a toy example

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10000)
])

model.compile(
        optimizer="rmsprop",
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
)

np.random.seed(0)
xy = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.random((200000,4)), np.random.randint(1000, size=(200000,1)))).batch(200)

@tf.function
def _no_return(batch):
    x, y = batch
    y_pred = model(x, training=False)
    r = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k=20).indices
    # True indicate that item is the correct prediction
    r = tf.cast(tf.equal(r, tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(y, tf.int32), 1)), tf.float32)
    # rank of the correct prediction, rank = 9999999+1 if no correction prediction within topk
    r = tf.add((tf.reduce_sum(r, 1)-1) * -9999999, tf.cast(tf.argmax(r, 1) + 1, tf.float32))

@tf.function
def _return(batch):
    x, y = batch
    y_pred = model(x, training=False)
    r = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k=20).indices
    # True indicate that item is the correct prediction
    r = tf.cast(tf.equal(r, tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(y, tf.int32), 1)), tf.float32)
    # rank of the correct prediction, rank = 9999999+1 if no correction prediction within topk
    r = tf.add((tf.reduce_sum(r, 1)-1) * -9999999, tf.cast(tf.argmax(r, 1) + 1, tf.float32))
    return r

#
# this run 1428.27 iterations/s 
#
for batch in tqdm(xy):
    _no_return(batch)

#
# this run 135.61 iterations/s 
#
for batch in tqdm(xy):
    _return(batch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of `autograph`. In the case of the `_return` function, because the `r` value is returned, it is generating the complete graph (with `r` as the leaf node). But, in the case of `_no_return` function, there is no return value, and the autograph does not set `r` as the leaf node, and because there is no leaf node the overall graph has nothing in it.

Thus, you observe this speed-up because the function is not computing anything.

Add any leaf nodes (as shown in the demo below)

```
def _no_return(batch):
    # your old code
    tf.print(r) # this will create another leaf node, 
    # or you can try
    tf.summary.scalar(r)
```

you will observe a similar performance between `_return` and `_no_return`. Also, if you remove `@tf.function` decorator, then also you will see the same performance.

lemme know if you have any more doubts.

Comment: Is this information (leaf node behaviour) available on tensorflow doc?